# Has Piggy done anything evil or immoral in Lord of the Flies?

Tags: lord-of-the-flies, william-golding

My class is having a discussion finding out whether Piggy has done anything wrong or immoral during the time that he was on the island, perhaps him being involved in Simon's death. Is there any piece of evidence that can support it?

Would really appreciate some input on this.